# How do you present contracts to clients?

Tags: client-relations, freelance, contract

Do you just put your Terms & Conditions on your website and make sure the link to them is very clear for clients to see and click on? Do you email them a link to make sure they see the Terms before progressing?

Or do you put them in an email as an attachment? I read that clients can get freaked out by contracts and I want to do this in a non-intimidating but still legally binding way.

Comment: Any client that "freaks out" merely at the mention of a contract will ultimately prove themselves to be a difficult client. Contracts are part of business.

Comment: Send the contract and the terms and conditions as attached files. This makes sure terms and conditions can't change while the game is played. It also makes absolutely sure the client has a copy. A link or any other reference to terms and services requires an action of the client. But the only important thing for you is to be sure that the client has a copy and agrees. If the client reads your terms or services or not is not your concern. Reference the attached terms and conditions from the contract. So the client signs for them both.

Comment: Put your terms in your timesheet, email link on your signature or collaboration system if you have one (eg. Basecamp, Freshbooks). You don't need to put these terms in their face, you can explain the terms to them by email simply and add the complete version in the same way they are added to any new software or game when you install them (eg. "by signing up you agree to.. blabla.) It's not true at all clients who refuse terms/contracts or aren't comfortable with them will be problem clients. When you know how to get paid and do good work, you rarely have issues ;)

Answer (score 4):

Most companies and designers put the contract as an email attachment in the form of a PDF to be signed and returned. This is standard and shouldn't cause the client any worry. This makes sure that both parties have a copy of it. If you happen to be physically near your client, doing it in person is acceptable as well.

If there is something non-standard in the contract, you may mention it in the email body itself in addition to being in the contract just to make sure they notice it.

Answer (score 3):

I usually don't send clients a "contract", but a "project proposal". The proposal includes an explanation of the work I'll do (and not do) for them, the deliverables, what I require from them (technically and content-wise), my fees, terms of payment and other general terms (copyright, source files, what happens if the project is cancelled).

In short, it has almost everything a contract should have, just presented a different way. It uses conversational language, and is worded in a non-threatening way (Not "the client shall pay 30 days after or be subject to late fees and litigation" but "The final payment will be made within 30 days of completion and deliveryof the project"). It also helps that it outlines in detail what BOTH parts are agreeing to. More of a way of stating how we will partner together.

I've never had anyone complain about it. I think the combination of it not being called a contract and having a friendly tone helps take away client reservations. And thankfuly I have never had to test its validity in court ;)

Comment: I'll expand my answer to explain it further. :)

Comment: This is a very interesting idea.